# Xtify 2.5 ARM64 Missing

Tags: ios, xtify

I added the new xtify 2.5 library to my app to update it on iOS.  Every time I try to compile I get error missing required arm64 architecture message.  What am I messing up on?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue it is because Xtify's SDK has not been compiled with the arm64 architecture or x86_64 needed for iOS 64Bit simulator.

Keep checking this page and hopefully they will update it soon.

http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/IBM+Push+Notification+SDK+for+Apple+iOS

Google Analytics only recently added support for arm64.

Answer (score 0):

Xtify SDK Version 2.6.1 (June 26, 2014) added 64-bit support. Any iOS version after that will have it.

Note that you still can't receive pushes in the simulator - that's an Apple limitation.